# read a file line by line and append word

Tags: python

I am a newbie to  python and trying to read file line  by  line and append a word at  the end of each line. The "print line" shows that the required word has got appended but the same thing not written back  to  the file as required . Appreciate your help.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
f=open('test1', 'r+')
for line in f:
    line=line.strip("\n")
    line=line +" " + 'test2'
    print line
    f.write(line)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, reading/writing a file at the same time is a really horribly difficult thing to get right.  Usually, you'll read from one file and write to a different file (possibly in memory).  An in-memory implementation would be something like:

```
with open('test1', 'r') as fin:
    lines = [line.strip('\n') + ' test2\n' for line in fin]
with open('test1', 'w') as fout:
    fout.writelines(lines)
```

Notice that I read all the file's data into memory in the first `with` block.  In the second `with` block, I write all that data back out to a new file (which conveniently has the same name as the old file effectively overwriting the old).  Of course, if memory is a problem, you can read a line and then write a line to a new file (with a different name).  After you've closed and flushed both files, then you can use `shutil.move` to rename the new file so that you overwrite the old one.

Comment: Thanks a lot team for your great  support

Answer (score 1):

mgilson's code is slightly wrong. Corrected:

```
with open("test1", "r") as f:
    new_contents = [line.strip() + "test2" for line in f.readlines()]
with open("test1", "w") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(new_contents))
```

Comment: Ahh yes.  I said `lines` where I meant `fin`.  Silly me.  In general though, iterating over the file object directly is definitely better than `f.readlines()`.  Also, your answer forgets to append the newline.  Maybe a `'\n'.join(...)`?

Comment: readlines() reads the '\n's as well, which is fine if the extra string was appended in front. however, appending it at the back appends it behind the '\n', leading to 'original\nextra'. seems the workaround is to strip the '\n' first and '\n'.join as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

[@mgilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/748858/mgilson)'s answer is very well, and just a little error is the `lines` in the end of `lines = [line.strip('\n') + ' test2\n' for line in lines]` should be `fin`.

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected.  In the future, please post this as a comment on my answer.  I'll get notified so that I know I need to fix it ASAP.

Comment: I'd like to add a comment on your answer at first, but I don't have enough reputation to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The code given by mgilson is great! However, the function you request is not possible if you read and append at the same time.

I am too new to python.
So, I find myself more comfort in the following syntax.

```
# read in 
f = open('test1', 'r')
newlines = []
for line in f:
    newline = line.strip("\n") + " " + 'test2' + "\n"
    newlines.append(newline)
    print newline,
f.close()
# overwrite the same file
f = open('test1', 'w')
f.writelines(newlines)
f.close()
```